# Etags: generate tag for Objective-C methods declaration

Tags: objective-c, regex, emacs, etag

How to make `etags` generate tags for both the declaration (i.e. inside the `@interface` block) and the definition (i.e. inside the `@implementation` block)?

The default behavior is only to generate tags for the definition. I've already tried to invoke `etags` with `--declarations` but that didn't solve the issue. A way would be to pass a custom regexp but I'm not that familiar with the syntax used by `etags`.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Tag-Syntax.html) says explicitly that tags for objective-c are "definitions for classes, class categories, methods and protocols", so I presume it's not possible normally with etags. You might be able to pull something off using the --regex option.

([GNU Global](http://www.gnu.org/software/global/) is another tagging system, which also does not support Obj-C directly.)

Answer (score -1):

Long shot:  Have you checked out Exuberant Ctags (http://ctags.sourceforge.net/).  It is a bit more powerful than ctags.  I long ago made the move from etags to ctags because of it, but I have never played with Objective-C.

- John

Comment: Here's a link to a fork of Exuberant Ctags with added objective-c support:  http://github.com/mcormier/ctags-ObjC-5.8.1